# What are the key ingredients for a good game-specific community website?

Tags: web, marketing, content-generation, community-management

Feel free to use an example. I am thinking things like guides, tools that help a player make certain in-game choices, discussion boards, services that enhance player interaction, mods, blog/news, etc. I am sure sites like this exist for really popular games like WoW. I am wondering what the community here thinks makes for a successful game-specific community website.

Comment: eggs, lots of eggs

Comment: I think in it's current state this is off topic as it's a "list of things" question. I think there might be a good question in here if you can narrow down a question to maybe specific parts of community sites and maybe ask for specific types of experiences / results seen from said features, etc. but as it stands I don't think this will stay open.

Comment: @SpartanDonut yeah I went to the gaming stackexchange first, but this one seemed more on-topic here based on the FAQ, I'm ok with accepting the fact that it's not going to fly on either site, but it was worth a try...

Answer (score 1):

Above all, I think it's the community. The community's demeanor is often not in the developer's control but there are things that can be done to promote a friendly culture. For example, rewarding players for helping newbies, a decisive ban every now and then, and giving players the power to reward other players for being helpful.

Next up is giving players the ability to feel proud about their game achievements. This can be something like posting replays for other people to analyze, hosting elite tournaments, talking about strategies, etc.. Mostly the standard forum stuff.

Finally, there's the developers themselves who must communicate with the community and make them feel like their effort and skills contribute to the game's development. Glance over every now and then, respond to some suggestions, and let them know if a suggestion was implemented.